# Why do panko breadcrumbs absorb less oil than regular breadcrumbs?

Tags: oil, breadcrumbs

In various sources I see that panko is lighter and airier and absorbs less grease but they don't back this up with why that would be the case.

My theories are

1. It's the crustless bread - doesn't make sense as it isn't the crusts that absorb grease
2. it's because it's they're baked after being turned into crumbs - but surely drying them out would leave more gaps in them for oil to enter?

Comment: Question #0 is: DOES panko actually absorb less oil?

Comment: How panko is made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFbQuHE4z7g

Comment: Yes. See Adam Ragusa https://youtu.be/n-hKc2QhJzc?t=337

Comment: Empirically, katsu & schnitzel/milanese will use whatever you put in the pan ;)